# Javascript regex & Japanese symbols

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, cjk

I use the `search()` method of the string object to find a match between a regular expression and a string.

It works fine for English words:

```
"google".search(/\bg/g) // return 0
```

But this code doesn't work for Japanese strings:

```
"アイスランド語".search(/\bア/g) // return -1
```

How can I change the regex to find a match between Japanese strings and a regular expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly Javascript is an "ASCII only" regex. No Unicode is supported (I mean that the Unicode non-ASCII characters aren't "divided into classes". So `\d` is only 0-9 for example). If you need advanced regexes (Unicode regexes) in Javascript, you can try http://xregexp.com/

And we won't even delve in the problem of surrogate pairs. A character in Javascript is an UTF-16 point, so it isn't always a "full" Unicode character. Fortunately Japanese should entirely be in the BMP (but note that the [Han unification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_unification) is in the Plane 2, so each of those character is 2x UTF-16 characters)

If you want to read something about Unicode, you could start  from the Wiki [Mapping of Unicode characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters) for example.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is there a way to change my regexp and not use third-party JS libraries(xregexp.com)?

Comment: @Andrei Technically this `"アイスランド語".search(/^ア/g)` will work. (in your limited example). But it isn't what you wanted :-) It's even more complex because Javascript doesn't have zero width look-back (in other languages you could have done something like `(?<=^|[ ,.;:/()-])` that means that before your character you want the beginning of the string or a space or a `,` and so on)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `\b`. As `\b` only matches:

- Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a
  word character.
- After the last character in the string, if the last
  character is a word character.
- Between two characters in the string,
  where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

(see: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

And in JavaScript a word character is the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` ([ref](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) / Word Boundaries / ECMA = ASCII).

Comment: Yes, this is interesting because it means that, although I'm sure Andrei has good reasons, \b ('word-boundary') doesn't seem to make sense in the context of Japanese anyway.
There are typically no spaces in Japanese and there's no definite algorithmic way of telling what is supposed to be a word boundary that I can see.
For example in: 私はアイスランドのごはんがすき the first は is serving as a word boundary but the same character is used again later where it is definitely not a 'word boundary'.
It's like you have to parse the language before you can decide whether it's a word boundary or not.

Comment: @PandaWood I thought the same, but as I'm still a novice in my Japanese studies, I didn't want to spill some superficial knowledge, which I could not explain properly. ;)